# I would like to know what the hex values mean in the following structure

Tags: c, embedded, firmware

I am discovering c code firmware and came across the following structure:

```
static void test_db_hd_fill_full(void)
{
    uint32_t err_code;
    uint16_t indexCount;
    rb_historical_data_t hd = {
            .time       = 0xAAAAAAAA,
            .max        = 0xBBBB,
            .min        = 0xCCCC,
            .Count      = 0x1111,
            .distance   = 0x2222,
            .activityTime   = 0x3333
    };
```

for some context...the firmware has a database that stores data of variables on a physical device.

I would like to know what the hex values represent in this structure. does it represent the start of a memory region for the specific variable? and if i were to remove all variables and replace it with only one variable...what hex value would be assigned to this variable?

Comment: You just have to lookup the definition of `rb_historical_data_t` structure. They don't appear to be memory areas, but just integers initialized using hex notation. In details, time is a 32 bit integer (`uint32_t` if unsigned), all the other fields are 16 bit integers.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni's explanation sounds right to me. It's unlikely that they are meaningful values, because (1) if min and max are unsigned 16-bit ints, then `max` is given a lower value than `min`, and (2) if they are signed 16-bit ints, then the values are negative, which also doesn't seem likely. So probably they are just there so that at firmware debugging time the values are easily recognized as initialized (as @Barmar's answer says.)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think they represent anything. They look like they're just easily recognizable values that can be used when debugging to tell when the structure members haven't been filled in with real values.